# Printing sum of double vector in gdb C++

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

Is it possible to print sum of a vector of doubles in while debugging in GDB? 
I know the values of a vector can be printed by *(vec._M_impl._M_start)@N, but I just want summation of huge array what can be done? One solution is to write C++ function and call it in GDB. Any other easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done via gdb script, but I think writing c++ function and calling it is better solution.

Nonetheless, the script (created by taking [STL support tools](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport) and modifying it) goes like this:

```
define pvecsum
    set $sum = 0
    set $size = $arg0._M_impl._M_finish - $arg0._M_impl._M_start
    if $argc == 1
        set $i = 0
            while $i < $size
                set $sum = $sum + *($arg0._M_impl._M_start + $i)
                set $i++
            end
        end
    printf "sum of elements: %f\n", $sum
end
```

So, you need to start gdb by something like *gdb -x abovesctipt.gdb myexecutable*, then to print sum do *pvecsum name_of_vector*.

Disclaimer: I have not idea how close the printed result is to the one obtained by similar c++ function.